# How to show certain numbers from an Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, numbers

I want to single out only positive numbers in one line and only negative numbers in one line, but they only show one by one with the text.
Here's my code:

```
int[] array = {2, -5, 4, 12, 54, -2, -50, 150};
    Arrays.sort(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < 0) {
            System.out.println("Less than 0: " + array[i]);

        } else if (array[i] > 0) {
            System.out.println("Greater than 0: " + array[i]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you sorted the values, you know all negative values come before the positive values, so you start printing values and then switch to new line when you encounter the first positive value.

E.g. like below, which can also handle an array of all negative values, an array of all positive values, and even an empty array.

This only uses Java constructs you've already shown you know.

```
int[] array = {2, -5, 4, 12, 54, -2, -50, 150};
Arrays.sort(array);
for (int i = 0, iFirstPositive = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < 0)
        iFirstPositive = i + 1; // Assume index of first positive value is next
    if (i == iFirstPositive) {
        if (i != 0)
            System.out.println(); // End line of negative values
        System.out.print("Greater than 0: "); // Start line of positive values
    } else if (i == 0) {
        System.out.print("Less than 0: "); // Start line of negative values
    } else {
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.print(array[i]);
}
if (array.length != 0) {
    System.out.println(); // End line if anything printed
}
```

*Output*

```
Less than 0: -50, -5, -2
Greater than 0: 2, 4, 12, 54, 150
```

Simpler, but slightly less optimal, you can also just do it with two loops:

```
int[] array = {2, -5, 4, 12, 54, -2, -50, 150};
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.print("Less than 0:");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < 0) {
        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Greater than 0:");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > 0) {
        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

*Output*

```
Less than 0: -50 -5 -2
Greater than 0: 2 4 12 54 150
```

Comment: Actually, your second solution has a complexity of `O(n)` while sorting the array has a complexity of `O(n*log n)`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Both have the same Big-O. My "slightly less optimal" comment is referring to the output, not the performance. The second version will always print 2 lines, even if there are no negative/positive values. The first version only prints lines when appropriate, and it comma-separates the values, which the second version doesn't.

Comment: Sorting an array in `O(n)`?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Both solutions sort (_O(n*log n)_), and both have simple loop (_O(n)_). Big-O complexity-wise, they are the same (_O(n*log n)_).

Comment: Ahh, right. But sorting is not necessary for the second solution.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn It is necessary for the desired output, where values are listed in ascending order. If not for that, why would question code include the sort? All other answers here have kept the sort too. It is also why my first solution starts with the comment *"Since you sorted the values, ..."*.

Answer (score 6):

You are currently printing a line for each element (and whether it is less than 0 or greater than 0), instead I would use an `IntStream` and `filter()` it for the desired elements (and collect those with `Collectors.joining()`). Like,

```
int[] array = { 2, -5, 4, 12, 54, -2, -50, 150 };
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println("Less than 0: " + IntStream.of(array) //
        .filter(x -> x < 0).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
System.out.println("Greater than 0: " + IntStream.of(array) //
        .filter(x -> x > 0).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

Outputs

```
Less than 0: -50, -5, -2
Greater than 0: 2, 4, 12, 54, 150
```

You could achieve the same result with a pair of `StringJoiner`(s) a `for-each` loop and (just because) formatted io. Like,

```
int[] array = { 2, -5, 4, 12, 54, -2, -50, 150 };
Arrays.sort(array);
StringJoiner sjLess = new StringJoiner(", ");
StringJoiner sjGreater = new StringJoiner(", ");
for (int x : array) {
    if (x < 0) {
        sjLess.add(String.valueOf(x));
    } else if (x > 0) {
        sjGreater.add(String.valueOf(x));
    }
}
System.out.printf("Less than 0: %s%n", sjLess.toString());
System.out.printf("Greater than 0: %s%n", sjGreater.toString());
```

Comment: Given the simplicity of the question, the use of streams is likely beyond the current level of OP, so this might not be the best of answers. Still useful, so +1 anyway. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas Good point. Added another example with a for-each loop.

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
String negative = "Less than 0: ";
String positive = "Greater than 0: ";
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < 0) {
        negative.concat(array[i] + ",");
    } 
    else (array[i] > 0) {
       positive.concat(array[i] + ",");
    }
}
System.out.println(positive);
System.out.println(negative);
```

Store the values in a string and then print them after the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to change your code as little as possible.

```
int[] array = { 2, -5, 4, 12, 54, -2, -50, 150 };
Arrays.sort(array);
boolean firstHalf = true;
System.out.print("Less than 0: ");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < 0) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    } else if (array[i] > 0) {
        if (firstHalf){
            System.out.print("\nGreater than 0: ");
            firstHalf = false;
        }
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use case for streams:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(array).filter(n -> n < 0).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using of `partitioningBy` (that introduced in java 8) is exactly for this situation. you don't need to sort array too.

```
Map<Boolean,List<Integer>> map = IntStream.range(0,array.length)
                .mapToObj(i->array[i])
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(a->a>0));
```

print positive number

```
map.get(true).forEach(integer -> System.out.print(integer+","));
```

print negative number

```
map.get(false).forEach(integer -> System.out.print(integer+","));
```

if you want to sort it you can do it like bellow.

```
map.get(false).stream().sorted()....
```